# Passing extra argument to the EndMethod when using Task.Factory.FromAsync

Tags: c#, asynchronous

I'm trying to wrap some legacy APM code over to async/await. I'm successful in many places using the Task.Factory.FromAsync method. Unfortunately, one of my EndMethod has the signature

`EndXXXMethod(IAsyncResult asyncResult, out uint number)`

I cannot find an overload for Task.Factory.FromAsync that can pass arguments to the EndMethod, only the BeginMethod. Is this usage supported?

Comment: You could always make your own wrapper using a TaskCompletionSource.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Is this usage supported?

No. `Task.Factory.FromAsync` only supports methods that follow the APM pattern *exactly*.

You'll need to fall back to the more general-purpose `TaskCompletionSource<T>`.